# How to fix GA Event Tracking inserted through jQuery in footer not sending reports to Google?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have a Wordpress site. I have a CTA Button created through a plugin which is MaxButton. With the use of my assigned class to such button, I inserted the Google Analytics Event Tracking onClick script through jQuery at the footer since there's no way I can implement that directly on the button. Here's the script of the button created by the plugin...

```
<a class="maxbutton-2 maxbutton maxbutton-free-report free-report" href="#freereport">
        <span class="mb-text">Claim Now!</span>
</a>
```

...And here's the GA Event Tracking Script that I have inserted into the footer that will supposedly send report when a user clicks on the button...

```
(function($) {
        /* For GA Event Tracking (Free Report CTA) */
        $(".free-report").click(function() {
            ga('send', 'event', 'Free Report', 'Claim Now', 'Free Report Claim', '0');
        });
})( jQuery );
```

With such codes, I have tested the site daily to gather reports if the code works. However, it's been a week and yet I have not seen any increase of my Goals that are being set. Can anybody here help me out? I have checked the suggested and similar questions here at StackOverflow yet noting seems to answer my question. Please provide me answers rather than just marking it as a duplicate, since it's this site's purpose. Please.

GA SCRIPT:

```
    var mi_version         = '7.8.0';
    var mi_track_user      = false;
    var mi_no_track_reason = 'Note: The site owner has disabled Google Analytics tracking for your user role.';

    var disableStr = 'ga-disable-UA-xxxxxxxx-x';

    /* Function to detect opted out users */
    function __gaTrackerIsOptedOut() {
        return document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1;
    }

    /* Disable tracking if the opt-out cookie exists. */
    if ( __gaTrackerIsOptedOut() ) {
        window[disableStr] = true;
    }

    /* Opt-out function */
    function __gaTrackerOptout() {
      document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
      window[disableStr] = true;
    }

    if ( mi_track_user ) {
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','__gaTracker');

        __gaTracker('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x', 'auto');
        __gaTracker('set', 'forceSSL', true);
        __gaTracker('send','pageview');
    } else {
        console.log( "Note: The site owner has disabled Google Analytics tracking for your user role." );
        (function() {
            /* https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ */
            var noopfn = function() {
                return null;
            };
            var noopnullfn = function() {
                return null;
            };
            var Tracker = function() {
                return null;
            };
            var p = Tracker.prototype;
            p.get = noopfn;
            p.set = noopfn;
            p.send = noopfn;
            var __gaTracker = function() {
                var len = arguments.length;
                if ( len === 0 ) {
                    return;
                }
                var f = arguments[len-1];
                if ( typeof f !== 'object' || f === null || typeof f.hitCallback !== 'function' ) {
                    console.log( 'Not running function __gaTracker(' + arguments[0] + " ....) because you are not being tracked. " + mi_no_track_reason );
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    f.hitCallback();
                } catch (ex) {

                }
            };
            __gaTracker.create = function() {
                return new Tracker();
            };
            __gaTracker.getByName = noopnullfn;
            __gaTracker.getAll = function() {
                return [];
            };
            __gaTracker.remove = noopfn;
            window['__gaTracker'] = __gaTracker;
                    })();
        }
```

Comment: How is GA implemented on page? analytics.js? gtag.js? GTM?

Comment: Hi @XTOTHEL, I have seen this encoded already at the site I am maintaining, so I presume that GA is implemented already. What I did is I just created a goal at the Google Analytics Dashboard and did what I did in the above scenario. The GA Script on the site is added on my UPDATED description of the problem, and I'm not pretty sure about it. I'm new to this anyway. Please hand me a help...

Comment: Thanks updated my answer. I believe it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the additional information.

It looks like the dev implemented GA on your page with analytics.js, **BUT** changed the function from `ga()` to `__gaTracker()`

Also note, the 6th parameter for the event value should be an integer, it is optional and if it is 0, you don't need to include it.

Thus your function from jquery should be just renaming `ga` to `__gaTracker`:

```
(function($) {
        /* For GA Event Tracking (Free Report CTA) */
        $(".free-report").click(function() {
            __gaTracker('send', 'event', 'Free Report', 'Claim Now', 'Free Report Claim', 0);
        });
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: When modified, I can see the reports right away right? In the Google Analytics > Realtime > Conversions then on the bottom page Goals.

Comment: Yes you should. Please double check my answer, I updated the function name. The “__” didn’t copy before.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work. Can you check the site instead and see if I did it right? Here is one sample page you can check onto: https://wem.technology/how-to-protect-your-business-with-dark-web-scanning/. There are 3 buttons on the sidebar, all of these buttons have event tracking pasted in the footer.

Comment: You have tag manager, as well as analytics.js on the page sending hits to the same GA property, tracking the page twice.

Comment: Where, what and how should I fix this?

Comment: search your code for "tagmanager" you'll see at the very top of the page, you're loading in tag manager and within tag manager you're already loading in the GA pageview tag. To fix, you need to remove one, if you keep GTM, then you need to re-do how you do the event tracking. If you keep analytics.js then you keep your jquery stuff as is and we can debug from there.

Comment: I think I'm gonna keep the Analytics.js. So how'd I remove the GTM? Anyway, there's a plugin installed called Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights on the site.

Comment: I actually you keep GTM and remove analytics.js. I can show you how you can track those buttons without any code on page after.

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199543/how-to-fix-ga-event-tracking-inserted-through-jquery-in-footer-not-sending-report

Comment: great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Too bad my account is just new. Can't enter to the Chat Room. Can you give me steps to follow instead?

Comment: Can you DM me on Twitter? We'll chat there.

Answer (score 0):

I made an unnoticeable mistake during the implementation. On the Analytics Dashboard, in my Goal Details, I have chosen the "value" as greater than 0. And as I have coded previously into my site, I am using 0 as the value in the script which makes the condition not able to met. So what I did is I changed the value as equal to 1 and changed the script's value as well into 1. @XTOTHEL gave me a great way to start with. First, since I am using MonsterInsight Plugin and as seen on the console, it is using the __gaTracker(''') rather than ga('''). So what I did is I changed this...

```
(function($) {
    /* For GA Event Tracking (Free Report CTA) */
    $(".free-report").click(function() {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Free Report', 'Claim Now', 'Free Report Claim', '1');
    });
})( jQuery );
```

...into something like this...

```
(function($) {
    /* For GA Event Tracking (Free Report CTA) */
    $(".free-report").click(function() {
        __gaTracker('send', 'event', 'Free Report', 'Claim Now', 'Free Report Claim', '1');
    });
})( jQuery );
```

And now, everything works as expected! Thanks @XTOTHEL!